# onHold input libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to have `onHold` or `onTouch` input for my game. So as long as the user touches the screen something happens (a car moves) and when he stops touching the screen it stops. How do I do that?

**I want my input in the `handleInput` area:**

***MyInputProcessor class***

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
```

}

***My PlayState class:***

```
 public class PlayState extends State  {

MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();


public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
super(gsm);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
 }

@Override
protected void handleInput() {

 if(inputProcessor.touchDown(**"asks for four ints"**)){


    }

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {

handleInput();
 }
```

**what do I add in `HandleInput` if I want the action to occur whenever the user                                                                                                       holds(keeps touching) the screen (anywhere on the screen).**

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InputProcessor` interface has `touchDown()` and `touchUp()` methods. Create a class that implements the `InputProcessor` interface and then give it to libgdx via

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

I thought I should also note that if you are using scene2d and you want to react only when a specific actor is touched, then you first setup an `InputListener` on the actor

```
actor.addListener(new InputListener() {
  public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      System.out.println("down");
      return true;
  }

  public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      System.out.println("up");
  }
});
```

And then give the stage to libgdx as the `InputProcessor`

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myStage);
```

Should you need more information about input handling, [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling) is the wiki page

**Edit:**

Since you updated your question, here's my updated answer.

Part of your problem is that your are using a `GestureListener` which is probably more complex than you really wanted. You don't need to know about longpress or tap or fling, just switch to a vanilla `InputProcessor` so that you have access to the `touchUp()` and `touchDown()` method.

The floats in the `touchUp()` and `touchDown()` calls are the x and y coordinates of the user's touch. If you give your `InputProcessor` to libgdx as described above, you don't need to call `touchUp()` or `touchDown()` manually. They will automatically be called when the user touches the screen.

As far as doing something like moving a car when the user touches the screen, here's a simplified example of how to do it:

On your car class, have a `boolean` that means whether or not the car is moving. On `touchDown()` set it to true and on `touchUp()` set it to false. Then in your render loop do an update step like this

```
public void render(){
    if(car.isMoving()){
       //move the car in the direction and amount that you want
       car.move();
    }
    //render the car
}
```

Now if you want to steer the car based on where the user touched, you would have to give the touchDown x and y location to the car class and let it determine which direction to go. Nevertheless, the basic principle is the same.

Comment: I'm kinda an amateur coder and I am new to `Libgdx`. I added my code in the question, can you show me how to implement the following using my code.

Comment: I tried to add the `touchDown` method to `handleInput` but it asks me to enter two floats. I don't know what does the float mean or do.

Comment: It might be worthwhile doing a little bit of reading about Java & how it works before you try to develop a game.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I mean, I do know what a float is, but I don't know what does it represent in the current situation.

Comment: I am not even sure if touchdown is the input I should be using

Comment: @spectacularbob It still asks me for floats, even when I implement an `InputProcessor`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but in your post you call `inputprocessor.touchDown()` manually. You do not need to do this. Once you give your input processor to libgdx via `setInputProcessor()` Libgdx will automatically call touchDown when the user touches the screen.